# How to use MultiDimensioning in Java to draw a "3D" Rectangle

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to achieve this image in java:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2c3.jpg

In order to create the rectangle in the middle, i need to use three dimmensional arrays. I do not what to do or how to start it. Also, after creating the array, how do i add the rectangles  on the window(probably a for loop).

I am trying to learn multidimmensioning in java and nothing online seems helpful to me. It just says.

Comment: If you don't know what to do, how do you know you need 3-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Image drawing doesn't really have anything to do with multidimensional arrays.  I would look for tutorials on drawing images first.

Comment: @ Hot Licks - Because this http://www.cs.uwlax.edu/~riley/CS120S13/Handouts/12.5_MultiDimensional.pdf

Comment: @omarahmed That pdf has nothing to do with drawing graphics. Those images are just visualizations of arrays.

Comment: *facepalm* then how would i draw this rectangle

Comment: @omarahmed Are you familiar with using the [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) or [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) class? They are used for drawing graphics. You should treat the 3D rectangle as three separate 2D shapes: A rectangle and two parallelograms, as it appears on a 2D screen. The parallelograms can be made using the [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Java FX` or `Threejs` technologies. Just check them out what meet your needs better.